# Constructor and copy-constructor for class containing union with non-trivial members

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, c++14, unions

I am trying to implement a custom variant type which uses a union to store data of various different types. In the field `type_id` I plan to store which type the data stored in the union is of. The union contains non-trivial members. Here is my current implementation:

```
struct MyVariant {
  enum { t_invalid, t_string, t_int, t_double, t_ptr, t_dictionary } type_id;
  union {
    int                             as_int;
    double                          as_double;
    std::string                     as_string;
    std::unique_ptr<int>            as_ptr;
    std::map<int, double>           as_dictionary;
  };
};
```

I try to create an instance of `MyVariant` like follows:

```
MyVariant v;
```

I get the error message: *Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of MyVariant*. So, I tried to implement the constructor manually like follows:

```
MyVariant() : type_id{t_int}, as_int{0} {}
```

That gives me a similar error message: *Attempt to use a deleted function*.
Next, I tried to implement the following constructor:

```
MyVariant(int value) : type_id{t_int}, as_int{value} {}
```

and construct my instance like follows:

```
MyVariant v{123};
```

=> same error message: *Attempt to use a deleted function*.

I've also started to implement a copy constructor, it looks like follows. However, of course this doesn't help with the compiler errors.

```
MyVariant::MyVariant(const MyVariant& other)
{
    type_id = other.type_id;
    switch (type_id) {
        case t_invalid:
            break;
        case t_string:
            new (&as_string) std::string();
            as_string = other.as_string;
            break;
        case t_int:
            as_int = other.as_int;
            break;
        case t_double:
            as_double = other.as_double;
            break;
        case t_ptr:
            new (&as_ptr) std::unique_ptr<int>(nullptr);
            as_ptr = std::make_unique<int>(*other.as_ptr);
            break;
        case t_dictionary:
            new (&as_dictionary) std::map<int, double>();
            // TODO: copy values from other
            break;
    }
}
```

I am using Xcode and Apple LLVM 6.1 as compiler.

The main question is: Why do I get the compiler errors which I'm getting and how do I have to modify my code to make it compile?

The additional question is: Am I on the right way with my implementations for the constructor and copy constructor?

Comment: That default constructor is OK. You need to implement a destructor.

Comment: Did you mean to use braces instead of parens where your one instance is allocated?

Comment: @donjuedo Yes, i meant to use braces because I'd like to stick to the uniform C++11 initialization syntax. Is there anything wrong with them?

Comment: @j00hi  No, I don't think there is anything wrong with braces, not directly anyway.  Having run into a mysterious (subtle) type casting problem recently, I am wondering if there is more going on under the hood to get that 123 to become an object.  My suggestion would be to try parens anyway, to see if directly passing an int to a constructor you explicitly choose would sidestep the error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your union has data members of type `string`, `unique_ptr` and `map`, all of which have non-trivial default/copy/move constructors, copy/move assignment operators and destructors. Hence all of these are implicitly deleted for your union.

*§9.5/2 [class.union]*

> ... [ *Note*: If any non-static data member
>   of a union has a non-trivial default constructor (12.1), copy constructor (12.8), move constructor (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding
>   member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union. *—end note* ]

So you must manually implement these for your union. At a minimum, for you to be able to create an instance of `MyVariant`, the class needs to be constructible and destructible. So you need

```
MyVariant() : type_id{t_int}, as_int{0} {}
~MyVariant()
{
  switch(type_id)
  {
      case t_int:
      case t_double:
        // trivially destructible, no need to do anything
        break;
      case t_string:
        as_string.~basic_string();
        break;
      case t_ptr:
        as_ptr.~unique_ptr();
        break;
      case t_dictionary:
        as_dictionary.~map();
        break;
      case t_invalid:
        // do nothing
        break;
      default:
        throw std::runtime_error("unknown type");
  }
}
```

Your copy constructor implementation looks valid, but what I'd do differently is instead of first default constructing the member, and then copying from the source object, just copy construct in the placement new call itself.

```
MyVariant(const MyVariant& other)
{
  type_id = other.type_id;
  switch (type_id) {
      case t_invalid:
          break;
      case t_string:
          new (&as_string) auto(other.as_string);
          break;
      case t_int:
          as_int = other.as_int;
          break;
      case t_double:
          as_double = other.as_double;
          break;
      case t_ptr:
          new (&as_ptr) auto(std::make_unique<int>(*other.as_ptr));
          break;
      case t_dictionary:
          new (&as_dictionary) auto(other.as_dictionary);
          break;
  }
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f37480f56036e6e)

Note that if the `unique_ptr` member is active, and is storing a pointer to some derived class instance via a base class pointer, then your copy constructor implementation will only copy the base class part.

Finally, unless you're doing this as a learning exercise, I'd strongly urge you to use [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/variant.html) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: Tidbit: `new (&as_dictionary) auto(other.as_dictionary)` and so on can get rid of some of the redundancy, and is more refactoring friendly.

Comment: Boost.Variant is quite outdated for the current state of c++.

Comment: @Orient Why do you think, Boost.Varant is outdated? And what would be a good, modern alternative to it?

Comment: @j00hi apply_visitor (integral part of Boost.Variant) not allow us to distinct ref-qualified visitor's `operator ()` properly.

Comment: @LucDanton Thanks, that is convenient. Reading your comment was a bit of wtf! moment though :) I remember reading a while back that `auto` can be used in a `new` expression, but had never used it, and that syntax does look somewhat odd.

Comment: @Orient Is that really a must have feature? Sure, there might be cases where it's a little more DRY to have ref qualified `operator()` overloads in the same visitor, but those situations should be rare enough that you can just create a differently named visitor to handle the `&&` case (unless I'm misunderstanding what you mean).

Comment: @Praetorian Having the universal library, I expect to find such a feature. I use multivisitors for AST transformations. It is the very use case, when I need in full perfect forwarding support (especially, when I compute n-th partial derivative symbolically).

Comment: What does `new (&as_string) auto(other.as_string);` do? I see that `auto(other.as_string)` constructs a new copy of `other.as_string` but what does the `(&as_string)` causes in combination with the `new`?

Comment: @abraham_hilbert It's [placement new](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) syntax, you're passing the address where you want the object to be constructed.

Comment: And you skip allocating memory too for this instance (so you don't need to delete it either, you just need to call the destructor on the instance)