# Vector of templated maps in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, hashmap

I am trying to do something that I thought should initially be trivial, but am running into design problems on how I should ideally structure this. I want to create a map of key-value pairs that stores a bunch of parameters. The "key" in here is always a string. However the value could be an int, double, string or char. I have enums to define the type:

```
typedef enum {INT = 0, DOUBLE, STRING, CHAR} val_type;
```

I was thinking of structuring it as a vector of maps

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, T>> params;
```

What is the most principled way to go about this?

EDIT: Updated the vector declaration.

Comment: What is the `int` in `vector`'s template arguments supposed to be? You need a `vector` of [Boost.Variants](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/variant.html).

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake there! It should just be `std::vector<std::map<std::string, T>> params;`

Comment: So, would a `boost::variant` solve your problem?  You could also write your own type-safe tagged union.  Another question is, how do you intend to use this vector of maps to `T`?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Unfortunately, boost is not encouraged at my workplace. I am basically trying to create a container to store parameters of several types. Each parameter would have a string name (key) and an associated value. However the value could either be an int, double, string etc. I was planning to use enums for types and then create a vector of hashmaps. Any ideas?

Comment: @AmmarHusain If Boost is ruled out, are you in fact restricted to at most C++11, and what is your compiler? If you can stretch to GCC 5.x with `-std=c++14` then you could `#include <experimental/any>`,
and employ an `std::map<std::string,std::experimental::any>>`, if an `std::experimental` library is tolerable.

Comment: @AmmarHusain Is Boost *discouraged* or *disallowed*? If it's the former, I'd say use it to solve this problem, it's by far the most convenient solution. If you're not allowed to, you need to [create and manage a tagged union](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30493617/241631), and use a `vector<map, my_variant_type>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got 15 minutes.  Incoming tagged union.  Not as good as `boost::variant`, and I might not actually compile it, but it should get you started.

```
template<size_t S>
using size = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, S>;
template<bool b>
using bool_t = std::integral_constant<bool, b>;

template<size_t...Ss>
struct max_size:size<0>{};
template<size_t S0, size_t...Ss>
struct max_size:size<(std::max)(S0, max_size<Ss...>{}())>{};

template<class...Ts>
struct max_alignof : max_size< alignof(Ts)... >{};
template<class...Ts>
struct max_sizeof : max_size< sizeof(Ts)... >{};


template<class X>struct tag{using type=X;};
template<class...>struct types{using type=types;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;

template<class T, class Types>
struct index_of {};
template<class T, class...Ts>
struct index_of<T, types<T,Ts...>>:size<0>{};
template<class T, class T0, class...Ts>
struct index_of<T, types<T0,Ts...>>:size<
  index_of<T, types<Ts...>>{}+1
>{};

template<class X>
struct emplace_as {};

template<class F, class...Ts>
void invoke( types<Ts...>, void* p, F&& f, size_t i ) {
  auto* pf = std::addressof(f);
  using operation=void(*)(decltype(pf), void*);
  operation table[]={
    +[](decltype(pf), void* p){
      Ts* pt = static_cast<Ts*>(p);
      std::forward<F>(*pf)( *pt );
    }...
  };
  table[i]( pf, p );
}

template<class T0, class...Ts>
struct one_of {
  std::aligned_storage< max_sizeof<T0, Ts...>{}, max_alignof<T0, Ts...>{} > data;
  size_t index = -1;
  using my_types = types<T0, Ts...>;
  template<class T>
  using sfinae_my_type = tag< size<index_of<X,my_types>{}> >;

  one_of():one_of(emplace_as<T0>{}) {}

  // brace construction support for only the first type:
  one_of(T0&&t0):one_of(emplace_as<T0>{}, std::move(t0)) {}

  template<class X, class...Args, class=sfinae_my_type<X>>
  one_of(emplace_as<X>, Args&&... args){
    emplace( emplace_as<X>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
  template<class X, class=sfinae_my_type<std::decay_t<X>>>
  one_of(X&& x) {
    emplace_as(std::forward<X>(x));
  }
  template<class X, class=sfinae_my_type<X>>
  X* get() {
    if (index_of<X, my_types>{}==index) {
      return static_cast<X*>(&data);
    } else {
      return nullptr;
    }
  }
  template<class X, class=sfinae_my_type<X>>
  X const* get() const {
    if (index_of<X, my_types>{}==index) {
      return static_cast<X const*>(&data);
    } else {
      return nullptr;
    }
  }

  template<class X, class=sfinae_my_type<std::decay_t<X>>>
  void emplace(X&& x) {
    emplace_as<std::decay_t<X>>{}, std::forward<X>(x));
  }

  template<class X, class...Args, class=sfinae_my_type<X>>
  void emplace( emplace_as<X>, Args&&...args ) {
    destroy();
    new(&data) X(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    index = index_of<X, list<T0, Ts...>>{};
  }

  template<class F>
  void my_invoke(F&& f) {
    my_invoke( std::forward<F>(f), index );
  }
  template<class F>
  void apply(F&& f) {
    invoke( my_types{}, &data, std::forward<F>(f), index );
  }
  void destroy() {
    if (index != -1) {
      apply([&](auto&& x){
        using X=std::decay_t<decltype(x)>;
        index = -1;
        x.~X();
      });
    };
  }

  one_of& operator=(one_of const& rhs){
    if (this == &rhs) return *this;
    destroy();
    rhs.apply( [&](auto const& x) {
      using X=std::decay_t<decltype(x)>;
      emplace( emplace_as<X>{}, decltype(x)(x) );
    } );
    return *this;
  }
  one_of& operator=(one_of&& rhs){
    if (this == &rhs) return *this;
    destroy();
    rhs.apply( [&](auto & x) {
      using X=std::decay_t<decltype(x)>;
      emplace( emplace_as<X>{}, std::move(x) );
    } );
    return *this;
  }
  ~one_of(){destroy();}
};
```

which is a quick sketch of a tagged union type.

Store a `one_of<int, double, std::string, char>` as your `T`.  Access via either `apply` passing in a function that has overrides for each, or `get<T>`.

The above is C++14, because it makes it easier.  It doesn't include an `apply` that has a return value, again because it makes it easier.  Both can be remedied, but it takes work, and really, you should look at how `boost` does it rather than use the above.