# Why std::get for variant throws on failure instead of being undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, variant, c++17

According to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) `std::get` for `variant` throws `std::bad_variant_access` if the type contained in the `variant` is not the expected one. This means that the standard library has to check on every access [(libc++)](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/6878e852d1d26cca0abee3013822311cd894ca3e/include/variant#L1325).

What was the rationale for this decision? Why is it not undefined behavior, like everywhere else in C++? Can I work around it?

Comment: @Justin I do not think it is a true duplicate. There is no answer 'why'. Second of all, there is actually no answer for 'can I work around it'. I am nominating the question for reopening.

Comment: Because that's what `std::variant` is *for*: 'a type-safe union'. If you don't want it type-safe, or want UB, don't use it: use a `union`.

Comment: [In this thread](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/std-proposals/DxvEBfamvZ0), some people give some motivation behind why `std::variant` might not have a `std::unchecked_get`. I don't know if that's really what was discussed in the standards meetings, but there is logic behind the reasoning

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Then half of the STL should be removed too, because there is UB everywhere and you can always implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found it!

Seems like the reason can be found under the "Differences to revision 5" in the [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0088r2.html) :

> The Kona compromise: f !v.valid(), make get<...>(v) and visit(v) throw.

Meaning - that the variant has to throw in "values_by_exception" state. Using the same `if` we can always throw.

Even knowing this rational I personally would like to avoid this check.
The `*get_if` work around from Justin's answer seems good enougth for me (at least for library code).

Answer (score 16):

The current API for `std::variant` has no unchecked version of `std::get`. I don't know why it was standardized that way; anything I say would just be guessing.

However, you can get close to the desired behavior by writing `*std::get_if<T>(&variant)`. If `variant` doesn't hold `T` at that time, [`std::get_if<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if) returns `nullptr`, so dereferencing it is undefined behavior. The compiler can thus assume that the variant holds `T`.

---

In practice, this isn't the easiest optimization for the compiler to do. Compared to a simple tagged union, the code it emits may not be as good. The following code:

```
int const& get_int(std::variant<int, std::string> const& variant)
{
    return *std::get_if<int>(&variant);
}
```

Emits [this with clang 5.0.0](https://godbolt.org/g/A92D1L):

```
get_int(std::variant<int, std::string> const&):
  xor eax, eax
  cmp dword ptr [rdi + 24], 0
  cmove rax, rdi
  ret
```

It is comparing the variant's index and conditionally moving the return value when the index is correct. Even though it would be UB for the index to be incorrect, clang is currently unable to optimize the comparison away.

Interestingly, returning an `int` instead of a reference [optimizes the check away](https://godbolt.org/g/sgxDFc):

```
int get_int(std::variant<int, std::string> const& variant)
{
    return *std::get_if<int>(&variant);
}
```

Emits:

```
get_int(std::variant<int, std::string> const&):
  mov eax, dword ptr [rdi]
  ret
```

---

You could help the compiler by using [`__builtin_unreachable()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) or [`__assume`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/assume), but gcc is currently the only compiler [capable of removing the checks](https://godbolt.org/g/T954ep) when you do so.

Comment: are you looking at the other decompiled overload of `get_int()` in [your own example](https://godbolt.org/g/A92D1L)? The variant-based one at disassembly line 1 does emit a tag check. The tagged union one does not. \n Also note Praetorian had a very good points about non-trivially-constructible types in the comments to [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48817600/1149924).

Comment: @kkm Yes. I put the tagged union there for comparison. It's clear that the tagged union emits better code, but in theory, this `std::get_if` method should work. The compilers have all the information they need.

Comment: @kkm Are you referring to my second assembly block? That's not in my posted example, but you can easily get it by changing the `int const&` to `int`. I'll add a link

Comment: Indeed the compiler does, and I also agree that the compiler assuming some invariants that make the program's behavior not undefined would not be unhelpful (and, as a side note, the general problem of inferring such invariants is likely undecidable :) ). \n Yes, adding a link would improve the readability and clarity of your answer IMO!

Comment: Yes, this works and I like the *get_if trick, thanks.
Real shame that we have to do it though.

Answer (score 9):

> Why it's not undefined behavour, like  everywhere else in c++? Can I work around it?

Yes, there is a direct workaround. If you do not want type safety, use a plain `union` instead of a `std::variant`. As it says in the reference you cited:

> The class template std::variant represents a type-safe union.

The purpose of `union` was to have a single object that could take values from one of multiple different types. Only one type of the `union` was 'valid' at any given time depending on which member variables had been assigned:

```
union example {
   int i;
   float f;
};

// code block later...
example e;
e.i = 10;
std::cout << e.f << std::endl; // will compile but the output is undefined!
```

`std::variant` generalized a `union` while adding type safety to help make sure you are only accessing the right data type. If you do not want this safety, you can always use a `union` instead.

> What was the rational for this decision?

I do not know personally what the rationale was for this decision, but you can always take a look at [the papers from the C++ standardization committee](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/) to get some insight into the process.

Comment: Are you serious? If it were that simple to replace a `variant` with a `union`, why would the former exist?

Comment: I thought that was clear -- to create a type-safe version of `union`. When writing `union`s in C, I remember always pairing a `union` object with an `int` or `enum` so that I could store information about which type in the union was set. Otherwise, I would risk UB if I read from the wrong data member. Here, `std::variant` provides the error handling and type recall for a union-type object, so you don't have to implement that yourself (other than checking that the type is correct).

Comment: I think there were some other interesting use cases for `union` depending on the data types contained which `std::variant` does not still handle, but I am not sure those parts about unions in the C standard were kept in the C++ standard.

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes. `variant` is a `union` plus type safety; naturally then, `variant` minus type safety is a union. I must upvote this answer, but @DanielDay please fix the language a bit. You mean to say "if you do not want type safety, use plain union instead of variant", but you actually say the reverse in the first sentence.

Comment: @kkm If all you care about is storing `int`s, `float`s etc. then this is an easy replacement to make. But what if one of the alternatives is `std::string`, or any other non-trivial type? You end up with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30492927/241631). You also lose other nice features like visitation. Yes, you could write all of it yourself, but then that can be the answer to any question that asks for an alternate way of doing something.

Comment: @kkm: It is not that black and white; by switching to `union`, you give up a _lot_ besides just that type checking. However I agree with Daniel that this is at least a valid workaround if you're really desperate for it.

Comment: @Praetorian: yes, I indeed agree about the non trivially constructible type part. Entirely missed this point, thanks!

Comment: @Praetorian this is true, although you could get around this limitation with non-trivial types by using a pointer to the non-trivial type. But you would then have to dynamically allocate memory for that type to use it within a `union` where `std::variant` can handle non-trivial types without additional allocation. I agree that the functionality is not a one to one match, but a `union` would be a work around for the OP's original question as stated

Comment: @DanielDay, managing pointers in a variant type is not same as using types or even smart pointers. Too much non-trivial cleanup would be involved; this is certainly not salvaging the proposed solution. Since the reasoning goes this far, I should be resetting the upvote.

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have not been clear enough.
It's really hard to do variant with union - if you really need tags & staff. (consider for example computing the size of the required index type or visitation).
What I meant was - I don't care much for exceptions, for me throw <=> terminate. I'm OK with UB instead of terminate if I messed up. I don't want an extra check when I'm out. I want get<...> with a wrong type to be a contruct violation.
Consider: vector is a type safe dynamic array and optional is a type safe union - this doesn't mean that [] out of range or operator* cannot produce UB.

Answer (score 2):

> What was the rationale for this decision?

This kind of question is always difficult to answer, but I'll give it a shot.

A lot of the inspiration for the behavior of [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) came from the behavior of [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), as stated in the proposal for `std::variant`, [P0088](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0088r3.html):

> This proposal attempts to apply the lessons learned from `optional`...

And you can see the parallels between the two types:

- You're not sure what's currently being held

  - in `optional` it's either a type or nothing (`nullopt_t`)
  - in `variant` it's either one of many types, or nothing (see [`valueless_by_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/valueless_by_exception))
- All functions to operate on the type are marked `constexpr`

  - This may seem coincidental or just good design practices, but it was very clearly intended that `variant` follow `optional`'s lead on this (see the linked proposal above)
- They each provide a way to check for emptiness

  - `std::optional` has an implicit conversion to `bool`, or alternatively the [`has_value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool) function
  - `std::variant` has [`valueless_by_exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/valueless_by_exception) which tells you if the variant is empty because constructing the active type threw an exception
- They each provide a way for a throwing and non-throwing access

  - Potentially-throwing access for `std::optional` is [`value`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value) and it may throw [`bad_optional_access`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/bad_optional_access)
  - Potentially-throwing access for `std::variant` is [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get) and it may throw [`bad_variant_access`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/bad_variant_access)
  - Non-throwing (I use the term a bit loosely) access for `std::optional` is [`value_or`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/value_or) which may return you an alternative (that you pass in) if the `optional` is empty
  - Non-throwing access for `std::variant` is [`get_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get_if) which returns a `nullptr` if the index or type provided is bad.

Indeed the similarities were so intentional, that an inconsistency in the base classes used for `optional` and `variant` were cause for complaint (see [this Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!searchin/std-discussion/bad_variant_access/std-discussion/UkRVuMTUakA/HxCHMBEDAQAJ))

So to answer you question, **it throws because `optional` throws**. Bear in mind that the throwing behavior should be rarely encountered; you should use a visitor pattern with a variant, and even if you do call `get` it only throws if you provide it an index that is the size of the type list, or the requested type is not the active one. All other misuses are considered ill-formed and should issue a compiler error.

---

As for why `std::optional` throws, if you check its proposal, [N3793](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3793.html) having a throwing accessor was advertised as an improvement over [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), from which `std::optional` was born. I haven't yet found any discussion about why this is an improvement so for now I'll speculate: it was easy to provide both throwing and non-throwing accessors that satisfy both error-handling camps (sentinel values vs exceptions), and it additionally helps take some undefined behavior out of the language so you don't needlessly shoot yourself in the foot if you choose to go the potentially-throwing route.

Comment: `valueless_by_exception` is not at all comperable to an empty `optional`. An `optional` being empty is a legitimate state; the object is completely functional (within its contract). A `variant` being valueless is not in a legitimate state. It can only get into that state via throwing an exception, and you pretty much can't do anything with a valueless `variant`. No visitation, no `get`, nothing.

Comment: Also, the whole argument fails, because while `optional::value` throws, `optional::operator*` *does not*.

Comment: @NicolBolas point taken about `valueless_by_exception`, but isn't "whole argument fails" a little extreme? I feel that the proposal makes it clear that the design was inspired by `optional`. `variant` has no comparable ` operator*` so it's hard to say that the behavior diverges there

Comment: @Nicol the non throwing operator* is rather an optimization similar to vector::at vs vector::operator[]. The fact that no such optimization exists for variant could come from the fact that variant is supposed to protect you from invalid access (by throwing) in the first place, no?

Comment: @rubenvb: Which is my point. The choice not to have a non-checking `get` has nothing to do with `optional`; it purely has to do with the design of `variant`.

Comment: @andyg - thank you! You are almost there, but as other commenters mentioned - I'd really like to know why no "operator*" like method.